# Pandas 5 Day Rolling Count Unique Days

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of sales in which I need to have a rolling count of days in which a buyer bought something for the past 5 days.

**The sales data looks like this:**

| DATE | BUYER | AMOUNT BOUGHT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | a | 2 |
| 1/3/2022 | a | 4 |
| 1/20/2022 | a | 3 |
| 1/4/2022 | b | 6 |
| 1/21/2022 | b | 10 |

The table should look back 5 days based on the date column and count all of the days in which the given buyer made a purchase. The amount of rows within the 5 day window is undefined, so I can't count the rows between.

**The table should look like:**

| DATE | BUYER | AMOUNT BOUGHT | 5-DAY ROLLING DAYS WITH PURCHASES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2022 | a | 2 | 1 |
| 1/3/2022 | a | 4 | 2 |
| 1/20/2022 | a | 3 | 1 |
| 1/4/2022 | b | 6 | 1 |
| 1/21/2022 | b | 10 | 1 |

I've been trying to use nunique on the DATE column, but haven't had success:

**What I have tried:**

```
df_five_days['5-DAY ROLLING DAYS WITH PURCHASES'] = df.groupby(['BUYER']).rolling('5D', min_periods=1, on='DATE').DATE.nunique()
```

The goal is to capture buyers, on any given day, who have bought in the past 5 days,  more than 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will suit you. I did it like this:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df['5-DAY ROLLING DAYS WITH PURCHASES'] = (df.groupby(['BUYER']).rolling('5D', min_periods=1, on='DATE').count()).reset_index().iloc[:, 3]
```

Output

```
        DATE BUYER  AMOUNT BOUGHT  5-DAY ROLLING DAYS WITH PURCHASES
0 2022-01-01     a              2                                1.0
1 2022-01-03     a              4                                2.0
2 2022-01-20     a              3                                1.0
3 2022-01-04     b              6                                1.0
4 2022-01-21     b             10                                1.0
```